# Bash script fails *only* from cron with “not a valid identifier”

Tags: bash, cron, functions

I have a script that creates a new log file each week that can be called from other scripts with a log file parameter. Without any arguments it creates a log with the name of the parent process in `~/bin/log`. This works fine in a terminal, but in a cron job it fails complaining that the function `default-log` is “not a valid identifier”.

The function seems trivial and everything it does works fine *outside* the function. I can easily work around this as the function is only called twice and I can just substitute the *whole 2 lines*, but I’d still like to understand what’s going on.

Other details:

- Not a root cron job
- The cron job is actually a script that calls this (`weekly-log "$LOG"`) but all the *echoed* paths, etc. in my debugging look fine
- Tested using “Run selected task” in gnome-schedule. This seems to produce the same environment, but you get to see the output.
- Ubuntu 16.04

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Start fresh logfile each Monday using the supplied path/name
# or create in ~/bin/logs with the name of the calling script

LOG=""
PARENT="$(ps -o comm= $PPID)"
DATEFORMAT="+%a %e %b %Y %I:%M:%S %P %Z"
# Thu 26 Jan 2017 01:52:49 pm AEDT

# Debugging—these all look OK
echo "Args: $*"
echo "PPID: $PPID"
echo "PARENT: $PARENT"
echo "HOME: $HOME"
echo "Default LOG: $HOME/bin/log/$(basename "$PARENT").log"
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin/log"

function default-log {
  mkdir -p "$HOME/bin/log"
  LOG="$HOME/bin/log/$(basename "$PARENT").log"
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo "No args"
   default-log
#   mkdir -p "$HOME/bin/log"
#   LOG="$HOME/bin/log/$(basename "$PARENT").log"
else
  DIR=$(dirname "$1")
  # dirname returns "." for invalid path!
  if [ ! "$DIR" = "." ] && [ -d "$DIR" ] ; then
    LOG="$1"
  else
    echo "Invalid path"
    default-log
#    mkdir -p "$HOME/bin/log"
#    LOG="$HOME/bin/log/$(basename "$PARENT").log"
    echo "Invalid path to log file: $1" 2>&1 | tee "$LOG"
  fi
fi

# Create new log or append
if [[ $(date +%u) -eq 1 ]] ; then
  echo "--------------------------------" 2>&1 | tee "$LOG"
else
  echo 2>&1 | tee -a "$LOG"
  echo "--------------------------------" 2>&1 | tee -a "$LOG"
fi
echo $(date "$DATEFORMAT") 2>&1 | tee -a "$LOG"
echo "" 2>&1 | tee -a "$LOG"
```

Comment: What does your cron line look like?

Comment: `40 16 * * * export LANGUAGE=en;/home/sean/bin/get-apod # JOB_ID_8`. My system locale is Irish, but errors are easier to debug in English. `get-apod` calls this script as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to POSIX, function names can contain only word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) (source: [part 1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05), [part 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235)). Change the function name from `default-log` to `default_log`.

But, Bash is normally very lenient about function names, so I'm not sure why it's failing.